# Aggregate function on related entities in jpa + Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I want implementation of method should to find all items,
that have a rating lower than passed as an argument. Using reviews associated with each item to calculate item rating.

Following are my classes

```
@Entity
public class Item {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Column(length = 100)
  @NotEmpty
  private String title;

  @Column(length = 200)
  private String description;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  Set<Review> reviews = new HashSet<>();

  public Item() {
  }

  public Item(String title, String description) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public Set<Review> getReviews() {
    return reviews;
  }

}

@Entity
public class Review {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Min(0)
  @Max(10)
  private Integer rating;

  @Length(max=200)
  private String comment;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private Item item;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private User author;
}


@Repository
@Transactional
public class ItemRepository {

  @PersistenceContext
  EntityManager entityManager;


 public List<Item> findItemsWithAverageRatingLowerThan(Integer rating) {

    return new ArrayList<>();
  }
```

I want to find all the items who has average rating  of supplied parameter.
Average of rating should be calculated from set of reviews present in Item entity

Comment: First you must create the `rating` field and calculate it for each `Item`. And after that you can easily create a sql query to find all the `Item`'s according to the given criteria

Comment: How can i calculate rating  for each item in query? because each item item has may reviews and reviews rating I have to aggregate and find average. How is this possible in query ?

Comment: Use grouping by item and aggregate function (AVG) and then filter out the values needed. All of the statements are fully supported in Spring (jpql, criterias, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on the following url:

[JPA / Hibernate One to One Mapping Example with Spring Boot](https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-one-mapping-example/)

Comment: I need to apply agrregate function on review which is set trying for that it is not available in link you provided

Comment: Better to use native SQL query that will have your aggregate function and everything to fetch the data from Database. You can follow this link for using native Query. https://github.com/ch0nch0l/AndroPOS/blob/master/androposweb/src/main/java/me/chonchol/androposweb/repository/UserRepository.java